# Download file in Fable

Tags: f#, fable-f#

How do I download file in Fable? Let's say I have a CSV data and I want to save it on my machine.

I tried using `ts2fable` with the `Download.js`. However, it creates just an interface:

```
// ts2fable 0.6.1
module rec Download

open Fable.Import

type [<AllowNullLiteral>] IExports =
    abstract downloadUrl: title: string * url: string -> unit
    abstract downloadBlob: title: string * blob: Browser.Blob -> unit
    abstract downloadText: title: string * content: string -> unit
```

I think there is a way directly import a .js module

```
let download = Fable.Core.JsInterop.importMember "../src/download.js"
```

But it doesn't look nice and elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `import` function in Fable in order to use the same syntax in JavaScript.

So in your case, it would give something like:

```
// If the file is in your src folder
let download : Download.IExports = import "*" "./path/to/download.js"

// If you use npm to manage the library
let download : Download.IExports = import "*" "download.js"
```

And you can use the code like that:

```
let anchor = Browser.document.createElement("a") :?> Browser.HTMLAnchorElement
anchor.innerText <- "Test download"

anchor.onclick <- fun _ ->
    download.downloadText("test.txt", "Hello, this is the content of the file.")

Browser.document.body.appendChild(anchor)
|> ignore
```

For information, I tested the code under Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. It works for Chrome and Safari but nothing happens under Firefox. I don't know if this is a limitation of Firefox or the library.